# ViewData missing from the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On my Orchestra Details webpage(at the following URL structure: orchestra/details/{id}), when I click on the Details link for a musician(that's supposed to take me to musician/details/{id}), I get a null reference exception in my Musician Details View file. It is thrown at the following link in my code to Create an Instrument, but I can't tell which variable it doesn't like:

```
<a asp-action="create" asp-controller="instrument" asp-route- 
id="@orchestra.Id" asp-route-musicianId="@Model.Id"> Create an 
instrument</a>
```

I've checked my Musician Details method in my MusicianController and I think it might be a model binding problem. I've also looked over my Musician Details View and don't understand why it's throwing the error.

--Musician Details Method in MusicianController file--------------------

```
public IActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int musicianId)
{
    var musician = _repo.ReadMusician(musicianId);
    if(musician == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Orchestra", new { id = 
        musicianId});
    }

    ViewData["Musician"] = musician;
    return View(musician);
}
```

--Musician Details View file---------------------------------

```
@using OrchestraManagement.DbFirstData
@model Musician

@{
    var orchestra = (Orchestra)ViewData["Orchestra"];
    //var musician = (Musician) ViewData["Musician"];
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id"/>
    @*<input name="orchestraId" value="@orchestra.Id" type="hidden"/>*@
    @*<input name="musicianId" value="@musician.Id" type="hidden"/>*@
    <h4>Musician</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Section)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Section)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SectionLeader)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SectionLeader)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Number of instruments:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Instrument.Count)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <hr/>
    <h1> Instruments For This Musician:</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                Serial Number
                </th>
                <th>
                Description
                </th>
                <th>
                Maintenance Date
                </th>
                <th>
                Condition
                </th>
                <th>
                Links:
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
   </table>
   <tbody>
       @foreach(var item in Model.Instrument)
       {
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaintenanceDate)</td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Condition))</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="edit" asp-controller="instrument" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-instrumentId="@item.Id">Details</a>
                <a asp-action="delete" asp-controller="instrument" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-instrumentId="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
   </table>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="create" asp-controller="instrument" asp-route-id="@orchestra.Id" asp-route-musicianId="@Model.Id"> Create an instrument</a> |
    @*<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Musician" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"> Create a musician</a> |*@
    <a asp-action="edit" asp-controller="musician" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"> Edit this musician</a>|
    <a asp-action="details" asp-controller="orchestra" asp-route-id="@orchestra.Id">Back to Orchestra Details</a>
</div>
```

--ReadMusician method in my Database First Orchestra Repository file-------

```
public Musician ReadMusician(int musicianId)
{
    return _db.Musician.Include(m => m.Instrument).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id 
    == musicianId);
}
```

Comment: Most of the posted code is junk. Go to the SPECIFIC line of the exception, as reported in the stacktrace (in a debug build), and reason about which expression evaluates to null - work backwards from there until the source of the problem is discovered.

Comment: That worries me a little. What's wrong with my code? What could I do better? I'm still in the learning stages when it comes to this type of programming, so I agree that my code doesn't look very pretty.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean "junk" as in coding! I mean "junk" as in "is not relevant to a question about a NullReferenceException". For an NRE, it's usually time efficient to go back to where it's thrown - once this is done there should only be a very small portion of code that could even potentially be relevant. Then just the relevant/related lines needed to be considered in further problem exploration and/or questions.

Comment: Ohhh lol good  I had to make sure. That makes sense. Cool, I learn new things everyday 

Answer (score 0):

In the view where the error is thrown, `@orchestra.Id` is accessed.

It was suppose to be set from

```
 var orchestra = (Orchestra)ViewData["Orchestra"];
```

But the controller action does not set `Orchestra` in the `ViewData` so `@orchestra` is most likely `null`.

That will cause the null reference exception when trying to access the `Id` property on a null reference.

I suggest you set the desired data in the action before return the view.

```
public IActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int musicianId) {
    var musician = _repo.ReadMusician(musicianId);
    if(musician == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Orchestra", new { id = 
        musicianId});
    }

    Orchestra orchestra  = //...code to get the Orchestra

    ViewData["Orchestra"] = orchestra;
    return View(musician);
}
```

Comment: @Nikosi So, in ASP.NET when you want to include Model data in a View you always have to use ViewData to set it in both the controller and the view ? Since I'm new to this type of programming, I wasn't sure about the role of the ViewData property. I also wasn't sure if this type of property has anything to do with including hidden input fields in my form. I'm thinking that my hidden input id, "@Model.Id" brings in the musician's id that was passed in my Details action method but I'm not totally sure if that's true. Aside from that, I fixed my problem. Thank you so much!